# Mouseover on rect borders

Tags: svg, dart

As the title says, is it possible to have an event when I hover over the borders (strike) of a figure in SVG? I'm making a rectangle around an ellipse and I want to be able to use the border of the rectangle in order to know what to do (resize width or height).

How can I do that with Dart? I haven't found anything, even for java to do that.
I was thinking to create two rectangle, one 1px bigger than the other one and use the mouseOver of the big one. IS that the only way?

Edit:
It would be nice to be able to understand when I'm hovering top/bottom or left/right

Edit2: To complete the answer given by [Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21148882/1259406)  (thanks!) here is how I detect in which part of the rectangle I am:
Edit3: now it works

```dart
_rectangle.style.setProperty("pointer-events", "stroke");
_onMouseResize(MouseEvent e) {
  int l_x = (e.offset.x-cx+rx).abs();
  int r_x = (e.offset.x-cx-rx).abs();
  int u_y = (e.offset.y-cy+ry).abs();
  int d_y = (e.offset.y-cy-ry).abs();
  if (l_x < rx~/20) {
    if (u_y < ry~/20) {
      window.console.info('top left ');
      _rectangle.style.setProperty("cursor", "nw-resize");
    } else if (d_y < ry~/20) {
      window.console.info('bottom left ');
      _rectangle.style.setProperty("cursor", "sw-resize");
    } else {
      window.console.info('left side ');
      _rectangle.style.setProperty("cursor", "w-resize");
    }
  } else if (r_x < rx~/20) {

    if (u_y < ry~/20) {
      window.console.info('top right ');
      _rectangle.style.setProperty("cursor", "ne-resize");
    } else if (d_y < ry~/20) {
      window.console.info('bottom right ');
      _rectangle.style.setProperty("cursor", "se-resize");
    } else {
      window.console.info('right side ');
      _rectangle.style.setProperty("cursor", "e-resize");
    }
  } else {
    if (u_y < ry~/20) {
      window.console.info('top ');
      _rectangle.style.setProperty("cursor", "n-resize");
    } else if (d_y < ry~/20) {
      window.console.info('bottom ');
      _rectangle.style.setProperty("cursor", "s-resize");
    }
  }
```

}
Note that rx,ry are the radius of the internal ellipse (not seen here). I build the rectangle according to rx,ry,cx,cy of the ellipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events) property to only invoke the mouseover effect on a stroke. You'd want pointer-events="visibleStroke" or possibly pointer-events="stroke"

If you couple this with a dart onmouseover handler...

```
element.onMouseOver.listen( (event) {
  print('onMouseOver!');
} );
```

That should give you what you want. If you want to do separate top/bottom/left/right handling you'd either have to work out where the hover is using the event co-ordinates or have separate rects for the different sides.